# finding vector in tetrahedron

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry

basically i have no idea how to even start doing this following question from last exam, so it goes like this:

In tetrahedron $OABC$, $$\overrightarrow{|OA|}=2, \overrightarrow{|OB|}= \overrightarrow{|OC|}= 1$$
$$\angle (\overrightarrow{OA},\overrightarrow{OB})=\angle (\overrightarrow{OA},\overrightarrow{OC})= \frac{4\pi}{3}, \angle (\overrightarrow{OB},\overrightarrow{OC}) = \frac{\pi}{2}$$
Let $T$ be a point of altitude(height) of side $ABC$ from point $C$. Find real number $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ so that $$\overrightarrow{CT} = \alpha \overrightarrow{OA}+\beta \overrightarrow{OB}+\gamma \overrightarrow{OC}$$

Sorry, had to translate everything from native language, as much as i could i explained.. I have no idea even how to start it

Comment: Are you sure for the condition $\angle (\overrightarrow{OA},\overrightarrow{OB})=\angle (\overrightarrow{OA},\overrightarrow{OC})= \frac{4\pi}{3}$?

Comment: only about red part i'm not sure,coz i rewritten it kinda messy $$\angle (\overrightarrow{OA},\overrightarrow{OB})=\angle (\overrightarrow{OA},\overrightarrow{OC})= \frac{4\pi}{\color{red} 3}$$ . It should be $3$ i guess

Comment: It seems not possible to me, check that point. With the given hint you should be able to find $A$ and then $T$. Finally we need to solve the system $ \overrightarrow{CT} = \alpha \overrightarrow{OA}+\beta \overrightarrow{OB}+\gamma \overrightarrow{OC}$.

Comment: maybe $\frac{\color{red}2\pi}{ 3}$?

Comment: I can't tell that I'm 100% sure that it's $\frac{4\pi}{3}$. I've rewrite like that from original test which i don't have. I'm pretty sure that it was $\frac{4\pi}{3}$ coz I tried some pointless stuff so in my mind it's familiar to me and it was 14 days ago. If it doesn't make sense then let it be $\frac{2\pi}{3}$

Comment: It seems that by symmetry the angle should be between $\pi/4$ and $3\pi/4$ for that reason I'm supposing that it is equal to $2\pi/3$. Anyway a way to solve is as indicated in the hint, the idea is to translate and rotate the tetrahedron in such way that $OB=\hat x$ and $OC=\hat y$ to simplify the derivation.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Let assume wlog

- $OB=(1,0,0)$
- $OC=(0,1,0)$

then by symmetry

- $OA=(s,s,t)$

for some some $s,t$ such that

- $\sqrt{2s^2+t^2}=2$
- $\angle (\overrightarrow{OA},\overrightarrow{OB})=\angle (\overrightarrow{OA},\overrightarrow{OC})= \theta$